# Access Query need to pick parameters from another Table at run time

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to delete and append the data from a Access Table **ULAE**. I want to create a parameter query where parameter needs to be picked from another table **LAE**.
This table has 3 columns(`Group,le,qtr`) that will be an input and will be part of where condition.

I am trying to run the query:

```
DELETE FROM t_00_unearned_unincepted_alloc_basis_table as ULAE
INNER JOIN [Table Valued Parameter] as LAE
ON LAE.le=ULAE.le;
```

It shows the error that specify the input table you want to delete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another table LAE has a field le which is equal to 02100, i Want my query to pick 02100 from the LAE table and delete the records from ULAE table.

Comment: Rather than parameterized query I can say it is picking arguement from another table

Comment: Am i making sense Sathish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
DELETE  ULAE.*
FROM t_00_unearned_unincepted_alloc_basis_table as ULAE
WHERE ULAE.le IN (SELECT le FROM LAE where le= parametervalue)
```